# laravel how to validate time between two values that crosses midnight (15:00 > time > 01:00)

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I have a request that looks like the following

```
"date" => "2022-05-25"
"shift" => "2"
"attendance" => array:1 [▼
  4 => array:5 [▼
    "present" => "on"
    "employee_id" => "4"
    "time_in" => "15:00"
    "time_out" => "01:00"
    "note" => null
  ]
```

knowing that each shift has its own starting and leaving time, also each shift has the option to be across midnight. for this case, we have the shift like this

```
#attributes: array:6 [▼
    "id" => 2
    "title" => "Evening Shift"
    "starting_time" => "15:00"
    "leaving_time" => "01:00"
    "across_midnight" => 1
    "user_id" => 1
  ]
```

**what I need is to validate the *time_in* and *time_out* to be between *starting_time* and *leaving_time***

for example, here (in this case) the valid values can be 17:00, 18:00, 22:00, 00:30 While 14::00 is not a valid value

this is my validation rules for now that works well if the shift doesn't cross midnight

```
public function rules()
    {
        $shift = Shift::find($this->shift);
        $rules = [
            'date' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d',
            'shift' => 'required|exists:shifts,id,user_id,' . auth()->id(),
            'attendance' => 'required|array',
            'attendance.*.employee_id' => 'required|exists:employees,id,user_id,' . auth()->id(),
        ];

        foreach ($this->attendance as $key => $Value) {
            $rules['attendance.' . $key . '.time_in'] = [Rule::requiredIf($this->has('attendance.' . $key . '.present')), 'date_format:H:i', 'nullable', 'after_or_equal:' . $shift?->starting_time, 'before_or_equal:' . $shift?->leaving_time];
            $rules['attendance.' . $key . '.time_out'] = [Rule::requiredIf($this->has('attendance.' . $key . '.present')), 'date_format:H:i', 'nullable', 'after_or_equal:' . $shift?->starting_time, 'before_or_equal:' . $shift?->leaving_time];
        }

        return $rules;
    }
```

here is what I get if the shift crosses midnight

```
The Time In must be a date before or equal to 01:00.

The Time Out must be a date after or equal to 15:00.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution for this.

I've created a rule using the command 'php artisan make:rule CrossMidnightTimeValidation'

inside the created file

```
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class CrossMidnightTimeValidation implements Rule
{
    private $starting_time,$end_time;

    public function __construct($starting_time, $end_time)
    {
        $this->starting_time = $starting_time;
        $this->end_time = $end_time;

    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute,  $value)
    {
        return ($value >= $this->starting_time && $value <= now()->endOfDay()->format('H:i'))
            || (($value >= now()->startOfDay()->format('H:i') && $value <= $this->end_time));
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Invalid Time (out of the shift time).';
    }
}
```

for my rules.

```
public function rules()
    {
        $shift = Shift::find($this->shift);
        $rules = [
            'date' => 'required|date|date_format:Y-m-d',
            'shift' => 'required|exists:shifts,id,user_id,' . auth()->id(),
            'attendance' => 'required|array',
            'attendance.*.employee_id' => 'required|exists:employees,id,user_id,' . auth()->id(),
        ];
        if ($shift->across_midnight) {
            foreach ($this->attendance as $key => $value) {
                $rules['attendance.' . $key . '.time_in'] = [Rule::requiredIf($this->has('attendance.' . $key . '.present')), 'date_format:H:i', 'nullable', new CrossMidnightTimeValidation($shift?->starting_time, $shift?->leaving_time)];
                $rules['attendance.' . $key . '.time_out'] = [Rule::requiredIf($this->has('attendance.' . $key . '.present')), 'date_format:H:i', 'nullable', new CrossMidnightTimeValidation($shift?->starting_time, $shift?->leaving_time)];
            }
        }
        else {
            foreach ($this->attendance as $key => $value) {
                $rules['attendance.' . $key . '.time_in'] = [Rule::requiredIf($this->has('attendance.' . $key . '.present')), 'date_format:H:i', 'nullable', 'before_or_equal:attendance.' . $key . '.time_out', 'after_or_equal:' . $shift?->starting_time];
                $rules['attendance.' . $key . '.time_out'] = [Rule::requiredIf($this->has('attendance.' . $key . '.present')), 'date_format:H:i', 'nullable', 'before_or_equal:' . $shift?->leaving_time, 'after_or_equal:' . $shift?->starting_time];
            }
        }
        return $rules;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own validation rules, i recommend use the [rule object validation](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-rule-objects).
But if you want to use [validation in clousures](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#using-closures) you can do something like this:

```php
$rules = [
    'time_in' => function ($attribute, $value, $fail) {
            if ((new \Carbon\Carbon($value))->lessThan(new \Carbon\Carbon($shift?->starting_time))) {
                $fail('The '.$attribute.' has to be less Than starting time');
            }
        }         
];
```

The validation rule is simple, write your complexity necessary.